# How have the various planes changed over the different editions of D&D, including changes of terminology?

Tags: dungeons-and-dragons, planes, edition-comparison

Dungeons and Dragons has been around for a long time now, and whilst there are a lot of questions and some very good answers covering a lot of the mechanical and lore-related differences between the various editions, I am struggling to get a good understanding of how the planes of existence have changed over the different editions. I know that a lot of things changed with the shift between 3rd to 4th, and again between 4th and 5th editions, but it's proving tricky to work out exactly what changed and in which order.

I personally am moderately familiar with 2e Planescape, and am currently running a 5e campaign. I understand that 5e tries as much as possible to be compatible with as many different models of the multiverse as possible, and leaves much to the DM to decide, but I would like to be better armed with a brief rundown of the changes and additions that happened in a chronological order, if anyone has the time to write such a thing (or link me to one that I might have missed).

Specifically I'm after statements such as "the name of ____ was changed to ____ in X edition", "in X edition, the planes of X, Y and Z were merged/combined/turned into domains/etc", or "X edition first introduced the realm/plane/domain/etc of Y".

Thank you.

Comment: Is there a particular plane or set of planes you are interested in? A comprehensive examination of the entire cosmology of D&D through editions is probably more broad than what you need.

Comment: Related: [Which editions of D&D used these various cosmologies as their default?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/163753)

Comment: I had missed that question on my initial searches, but that is pretty much exactly what I was after. If you make your comment into an answer, I'll be happy to accept it, as the only answer to it seems to cover pretty much all of my question.

Comment: In that case, we can get this changed over to a duplicate if you think that question covers what you're looking for here.

Comment: I think that would be appropriate, sure. Thank you.

Comment: Done! And by the way: Welcome to RPG.SE! Take the [tour] if you haven't already, and check out the [help] for more guidance.